# event.stopPropagation() still not working on firefox but on chrome it's work fine

Tags: jquery, html, css

i opened a lot of same problem about this event.stopPropagation() on firefox  but i still didn't find the solution for my case.

here is the example of code that i use on my local page.
[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/yy/pen/vOYqYV)

So everytime i click on the *select option*, the firefox console said that `ReferenceError: event is not defined` and the source is **`event.stopPropagation();`**

Please help, what is the solution?

Comment: Well, there is no `event` variable defined in your code, no magic there. You need to add it as a parameter to the click event handler: `$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function(event) { ... }`

Comment: @Akbar some browsers make the event a global variable when one happens, but this is not standardized behavior across browsers.  So if you need the event, you should always explicitly put it on the event handler's argument list.

Comment: thanks @Taplar for reminding me. sometime i forgot put the event but i didn't relize it cuz i used google chrome all the time. well noted